# How to export a table made with tab_df function (sjPlot library) as a png document in R version 3.5.3

Tags: r, export, png, sjplot

I am trying to export the table with the `tab_df` command. However, when I try to export it, R says, "Error in 1:nrow(x) : argument of length 0". What other ways can I try to export my table with the `tab_df` function?

```
mydataframe <- tab_df(old_data_frame, alternate.rows = TRUE, title = "Table 2. RNA Sequences", show.footnote = TRUE, footnote = "Abbreviations - RNA: ribonucleicacid.")

png("~/Desktop/name_of_picture.png")
tab_df(mydataframe)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tab_df` function has a `file` argument which allows to save the image in a HTML file. Then you can use the `webshot` package to export it as png.

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_df(old_data_frame, alternate.rows = TRUE, title = "Table 2. RNA Sequences", show.footnote = TRUE, footnote = "Abbreviations - RNA: ribonucleicacid.", 
       file = "name_of_picture.html")

library(webshot)
webshot("name_of_picture.html", "name_of_picture.png")
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. webshot worked to give me the table as a png, but it changed the format, the font and a greek letter (unit symbol) into another symbol. Do you know what I can do about it?